# timeout during ssh connection

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I have an ubuntu pc in my office. I can use this computer through teamviewer.  But I not use ssh connection.

This is my office computer:

```
donbeo@donbeo-OptiPlex-790:~$ sudo service ssh status
[sudo] password for donbeo: 
ssh start/running, process 4093
donbeo@donbeo-OptiPlex-790:~$
```

When I try to log in from remote using ssh I receive a timeout error. 
This is the result of my ping:

```
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ ping 149.157.140.64
PING 149.157.140.64 (149.157.140.64) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 149.157.140.64 ping statistics ---
167 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 167327ms

donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$
```

I was able to do ssh connection since few days ago. 
I do not know why I am not able anymore to connect using ssh. 
I suppose this is due a software update. (I am not sure about that)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is a firewall setup in the office - that can block SSH.

Comment: I will ask to the IT but since yesterday I was able to login

Comment: You are right it was the firewall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check whether there is a firewall setup, blocking the port SSH uses.

By default, SSH uses port 22 (there is also a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)).